# Arranging two plots in one window in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend

I have two plots named fig and fig2. Each plot contains 4 geom_ablines and one plot contains legend as well.

I want to plot them in one window vertically aligned. I am using **ggarrange** function in R but when it plots them, it does not show the geom_ablines and also messes the legend.

However, if I plot them individually, they are fine. The code I am using is:

```
# First Plot
    fig <- ggplot(scalingdata, aes(x=Re, y=Sw, color=Size)) + 
      geom_point(size=3) +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#f0f4f5",
                                            size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.border = element_rect(color = "black",fill = NA,size = 1),
            plot.title = element_text(size = 25, face = "italic"),
            axis.title.y = element_text(size=17.5),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size=15, face="bold"),
            axis.title.x = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_blank(),
            legend.title =element_blank(),
            legend.text = element_text(size=15, face="bold"),
            legend.position = c(0.2, 0.7))+
      scale_x_log10(limits = c(1,10^8), breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                    labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) + 
      scale_y_log10(limits = c(1,10^8), breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                    labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) + annotation_logticks()
    
    lines <- data.frame(name = c("Sw ~ Re^13/15", "Sw ~ Re^9/10", "Sw ~ Re^2/3", "Sw ~ Re^3/4"),
                        intercept = c(1, 0.79, 1.35, 1.1),
                        slope = c(13/15, 9/10, 2/3, 3/4))

    fig + geom_abline(data = lines, aes(intercept=intercept, slope=slope, color=name, size=name, linetype=name))+
      scale_color_manual(name='Size',
                         values=c("Sw ~ Re^13/15" ='#e66419', "Sw ~ Re^9/10" ='#e66419',
                                  "Sw ~ Re^2/3" ='#278ccf', "Sw ~ Re^3/4" ='#278ccf',
                                  'Fish' = '#e66419', 'Larvae' = '#278ccf'),
                         breaks=lines$name) +
      scale_size_manual(name='Size',
                        values=c("Sw ~ Re^13/15" =1, "Sw ~ Re^9/10" =1.25, "Sw ~ Re^2/3" =1, "Sw ~ Re^3/4" = 1.25)) +
      scale_linetype_manual(name='Size',
                            values=c("Sw ~ Re^13/15" ='solid', "Sw ~ Re^9/10" ='dashed',
                                     "Sw ~ Re^2/3" ='solid', "Sw ~ Re^3/4" ='dashed'))
    
# Second Plot    
    fig2 <- ggplot(scalingdata, aes(x=Re, y=St, color=Size)) + 
      geom_point(size=3) + 
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#f0f4f5",
                                            size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.border = element_rect(color = "black",fill = NA,size = 1),
            plot.title = element_text(size = 25, face = "italic"),
            axis.title=element_text(size=17.5),
            axis.text = element_text(size=15, face="bold"),
            legend.position ="none") +                                   # If no legend to be shown
      scale_x_log10(limits = c(1,10^8), breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                                 labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) + 
      scale_y_log10(limits = c(10^-1,10^1), #breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                    labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) + annotation_logticks()
    
    lines1 <- data.frame(name = c("St ~ Re^-2/15", "St ~ Re^-1/10", "St ~ Re^-1/3", "St ~ Re^-1/4"),
                        intercept = c(0.15, 0.03, 0.55, 0.38),
                        slope = c(-2/15, -1/10, -1/3, -1/4))
    
    fig2 + geom_abline(data = lines1, aes(intercept=intercept, slope=slope, color=name, size=name, linetype=name))+
      scale_color_manual(name='Size',
                         values=c("St ~ Re^-2/15" ='#e66419', "St ~ Re^-1/10" ='#e66419',
                                  "St ~ Re^-1/3" ='#278ccf', "St ~ Re^-1/4" ='#278ccf',
                                  'Fish' = '#e66419', 'Larvae' = '#278ccf'),
                         breaks=lines$name) +
      scale_size_manual(name='Size',
                        values=c("St ~ Re^-2/15" =1, "St ~ Re^-1/10" =1.25, "St ~ Re^-1/3" =1, "St ~ Re^-1/4" = 1.25)) +
      scale_linetype_manual(name='Size',
                            values=c("St ~ Re^-2/15" ='solid', "St ~ Re^-1/10" ='dashed',
                                     "St ~ Re^-1/3" ='solid', "St ~ Re^-1/4" ='dashed'))
    
    library(ggpubr)
    ggarrange(fig, fig2, widths=c(1.8,1.8),heights=c(1.8,1.5),ncol=1,nrow=2, align='v')
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?

The MRE is:

```
structure(list(Sw = c(118612, 119946, 122211, 122442, 124753, 
126631, 128301, 128781, 135193, 137232, 137489, 137744, 138263, 
141664, 144336, 150394, 152376, 152664, 156417, 158480, 160867, 
162985, 170000, 172000, 172000, 175000, 183000, 185000, 185000, 
193000, 198000, 202000, 206000, 209000, 213000, 213000, 214000, 
221000, 221000, 221000, 221000, 232000, 236000, 236000, 240000, 
240000, 241000, 248000, 251000, 256000, 258000, 260000, 271000, 
272000, 274000, 292000, 297000, 299000, 308000, 315000, 327000, 
327000, 329000, 342000, 359000, 366000, 368000, 376000, 377000, 
387000, 394000, 396000, 407000, 416000, 420000, 428000, 431000, 
456000, 456000, 463000, 473000, 490000, 491000, 498000, 512000, 
518000, 524000, 528000, 574000, 592000, 609000, 611000, 631000, 
634000, 646000, 669000, 672000, 677000, 703000, 751000, 762000, 
781000, 794000, 823000, 846000, 849000, 853000, 882000, 887000, 
898000, 941000, 979000, 1030000, 1060000, 1070000, 1080000, 1090000, 
1140000, 1170000, 6469900, 7584900, 7914000, 7995300, 8139300, 
8254100, 8482100, 8485600, 8557900, 8642000, 8730800, 8734400, 
8779000, 8812900, 8869100, 8902600, 8914600, 8975200, 9075000, 
9203000, 9269900, 9481200, 9565700, 9656200, 9664300, 9821400, 
9825700, 9989900, 10410400, 10552900, 10820800, 10959400, 11449900, 
11855900, 41766.8, 44815, 46421, 51017, 52530, 54453, 55151, 
60703, 60748, 61022, 61850, 62083, 64308, 65524, 66017, 66115, 
66963, 69001, 70887, 74872, 74928, 76174, 85619, 85940, 300720, 
349790, 414460, 507870, 538620, 540430, 570270, 595730, 617120, 
667810, 687150, 697620, 704690, 717830, 741100, 754920, 760010, 
769000, 825210, 875180, 899020, 1042220, 1665250, 1687780, 1930520, 
2071620, 1484730, 1560040, 2205640, 3198090, 3225130, 4840500, 
73.698, 91.148, 91.843, 126.687, 130.467, 155.199, 232.717, 602.22, 
615.05, 619.05, 626.62, 655.73, 677.34, 747.73, 768.65, 778.66, 
816.82, 859.61, 885.06, 906.12, 925.43, 975.49, 1020.79, 1024.12, 
1091.84, 1094.5, 1114.2, 1122.36, 1165.94, 1290.31, 1291.33, 
1302.88, 1361.19, 1477.34, 1543.46, 1564.86, 1609.89, 1679.22, 
1720.21, 1748.66, 1769.04, 1778.18, 1804.09, 1816.32, 1842.21, 
1861.27, 1861.88, 1875.09, 1957.71, 1975.41, 2028.23, 2049.21, 
2193.15, 2214.41, 2320.91, 190.301, 213.437, 215.963, 217.451, 
226.594, 227.932, 243.172, 244.607, 292.403, 297.318, 308.91, 
310.428, 319.697, 332.16, 339.738, 345.449, 363.165, 388.971, 
399.016, 414.572, 415.794, 453.714), Re = c(77600, 36434, 49900, 
70000, 81300, 54900, 83300, 73400, 49100, 70000, 78800, 53200, 
86600, 79400, 71700, 50700, 58000, 97400, 64200, 92200, 79400, 
70000, 69500, 95900, 54800, 74500, 128000, 61200, 94400, 121000, 
108000, 139000, 102000, 156000, 46100, 125000, 83200, 113000, 
123000, 94400, 146000, 88600, 82600, 155000, 102000, 155000, 
125000, 169000, 122000, 81900, 114000, 159000, 133000, 155000, 
114000, 169000, 144000, 209000, 156000, 189000, 137000, 168000, 
186000, 187000, 184000, 186000, 246000, 152000, 231000, 332000, 
202000, 222000, 239000, 214000, 302000, 219000, 307000, 260000, 
312000, 241000, 348000, 235000, 196000, 324000, 244000, 324000, 
357000, 250000, 357000, 380000, 337000, 3e+05, 351000, 414000, 
389000, 293000, 417000, 335000, 374000, 512000, 401000, 343000, 
537000, 414000, 595000, 392000, 448000, 421000, 633000, 496000, 
633000, 466000, 648000, 524000, 729000, 516000, 504000, 795000, 
802000, 4114000, 3809200, 4687400, 4130800, 4228400, 4891300, 
3757100, 3974800, 4798000, 4516600, 4074300, 4310400, 4479500, 
3904400, 4358000, 6464600, 3851100, 4824400, 4412200, 5069000, 
4642300, 4316300, 6473400, 4096700, 4572600, 5340600, 5041200, 
5224500, 5429300, 5481800, 5952800, 7097300, 7165900, 7781600, 
25778, 29630, 20784, 28523, 38410, 36744, 33414, 56160, 41702, 
49165, 30384, 42771, 33623, 46439, 47329, 24810, 38161, 56150, 
51390, 47929, 54400, 56860, 59810, 67890, 303110, 236540, 282380, 
354240, 408170, 391180, 377560, 408170, 391180, 402420, 526760, 
435040, 411070, 585800, 508420, 450730, 497730, 463680, 477010, 
745400, 553540, 846800, 889800, 935100, 1047300, 1148400, 553800, 
723800, 746600, 1720200, 2939400, 2374500, 10.115, 10.11, 12.227, 
29.025, 20.106, 10.165, 17.613, 83.12, 105.2, 123.1, 148.64, 
113.79, 111.14, 333.77, 120.21, 283, 206.68, 287.45, 341.67, 
318.34, 291.98, 366.66, 456.8, 296.57, 467.7, 439.2, 415.7, 390.39, 
456.8, 308.38, 478.8, 671.2, 606, 587.2, 542.8, 749, 760.9, 692.4, 
659.3, 667.6, 643, 560.6, 777.7, 686.5, 735.2, 856.6, 690.8, 
870, 710.4, 894.7, 730.6, 825, 817.3, 920.1, 880.8, 25.031, 32.901, 
29.787, 27.193, 23.62, 29.056, 30.791, 23.425, 30.537, 36.339, 
50.199, 58.272, 52.758, 54.085, 68.21, 27.193, 71.09, 50.617, 
48.967, 44.702, 73.49, 73.49), Species = c("Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", 
"Dace, Trout, and Goldfish", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", 
"Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Giant Bluefin Tuna", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", 
"Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", 
"Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", 
"Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", 
"Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Stingrays", 
"Stingrays", "Stingrays", "Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", 
"Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", 
"Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", 
"Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", 
"Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", 
"Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", 
"Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", 
"Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", 
"Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", "Saithe and Mackerel", 
"Sharks", "Sharks", "Sharks", "Sharks", "Sharks", "Sharks", "Ascidian Larvae", 
"Ascidian Larvae", "Ascidian Larvae", "Ascidian Larvae", "Ascidian Larvae", 
"Ascidian Larvae", "Ascidian Larvae", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish40", 
"Larval Zebrafish40", "Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", 
"Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", 
"Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", 
"Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", 
"Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", 
"Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", 
"Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61", 
"Larval Zebrafish61", "Larval Zebrafish61"), Size = c("Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", 
"Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae", "Larvae"
), St = c(0.243268582034501, 0.523959877133545, 0.389788362056428, 
0.278388628178544, 0.244219067477153, 0.367102048635318, 0.245134340978561, 
0.279238212500755, 0.438219631492664, 0.31201571537706, 0.277690390877163, 
0.412078707080919, 0.254101483129468, 0.283960618825043, 0.320386808203692, 
0.472108334099284, 0.418126498248202, 0.249457632595693, 0.387764494072905, 
0.273566338387061, 0.322452372293089, 0.370568682018262, 0.38929895045003, 
0.285449282566378, 0.499536244491161, 0.373853018937899, 0.227541300611154, 
0.481104503595853, 0.311902495975278, 0.253858117251408, 0.291783380018674, 
0.231289376443841, 0.321429819699716, 0.213226316167493, 0.73535626042963, 
0.271199388846448, 0.409363920393332, 0.311266904187258, 0.28596065181431, 
0.372597035732629, 0.240912055980549, 0.416747860646413, 0.454727345483648, 
0.242325669270641, 0.374481343339475, 0.246432884004042, 0.306850012732366, 
0.233552269751365, 0.327440961481463, 0.497479489076128, 0.360191923659416, 
0.260252757478063, 0.324292396384391, 0.279290601871247, 0.382529407297209, 
0.274988962771768, 0.328256302521008, 0.227690032080688, 0.314228255404726, 
0.265257618198795, 0.37987988825258, 0.309783004110735, 0.281515343185172, 
0.291074135050228, 0.310524407391415, 0.313175123421803, 0.23808488657843, 
0.393698149116106, 0.259745771586872, 0.185520538993253, 0.310430202684134, 
0.283897342720872, 0.271028913657513, 0.309384586459903, 0.221340793993696, 
0.311041809833107, 0.223438501844327, 0.279132632073809, 0.232610526728174, 
0.305761686039938, 0.216322161048327, 0.331854211704024, 0.398698440415127, 
0.244626470116666, 0.333963689797827, 0.254450826346251, 0.233605028464149, 
0.336134453781513, 0.255895584615308, 0.247946068379505, 0.287611672670147, 
0.324144809438927, 0.286115482193914, 0.243729463678313, 0.264302963531755, 
0.363393883771318, 0.256479308531784, 0.321634759738359, 0.299159527690512, 
0.233447427266361, 0.302433374165808, 0.362389853900744, 0.235323518267981, 
0.316386985184939, 0.226293726046568, 0.344699568138944, 0.303033145076212, 
0.333430716272689, 0.223017542504579, 0.288146783640142, 0.236594709692005, 
0.334361212296077, 0.252977172911813, 0.321953903004644, 0.233601359236799, 
0.333114218203138, 0.344203337900817, 0.228221648865378, 0.232183102213908, 
0.250295128437197, 0.316909457357351, 0.268709577645423, 0.308048935041855, 
0.306358622430061, 0.268574355248053, 0.359310368633893, 0.339771064454215, 
0.283874302307228, 0.3045241557553, 0.341051647591493, 0.322503638696486, 
0.311913824779625, 0.359239145081061, 0.323900368274474, 0.219176667244061, 
0.368414047393468, 0.296087410852063, 0.327348653980426, 0.288952360656955, 
0.317805173505505, 0.349599499061661, 0.23518164782688, 0.375138127690756, 
0.336377010833042, 0.292686346632698, 0.310204924915008, 0.304323523404437, 
0.30517060120053, 0.306385178491378, 0.289305836077696, 0.245760867447159, 
0.254302170218483, 0.242484923070044, 0.257870165748749, 0.240719274240546, 
0.355471244064845, 0.2846681185215, 0.217661796677678, 0.235860109140741, 
0.262690301692974, 0.17202920082822, 0.231843122013434, 0.197537480456343, 
0.323976771042564, 0.231016184479705, 0.304402110063851, 0.224562202134299, 
0.221997238656593, 0.424123516982184, 0.279276421804133, 0.195580134425664, 
0.219536681625896, 0.248622358777944, 0.219212016357345, 0.213215622321579, 
0.227832389358595, 0.20146919759615, 0.157899648862937, 0.235354178413181, 
0.233597292524979, 0.228178161508506, 0.210019930393074, 0.219878073423756, 
0.240388487016993, 0.232288390949214, 0.251079985698921, 0.264114641433334, 
0.207614593756514, 0.255216558855981, 0.272835854188107, 0.19502547907645, 
0.231992157091137, 0.266565280053204, 0.243021448263837, 0.263953297612413, 
0.27533163553866, 0.186864632918074, 0.258487448689974, 0.195883416277148, 
0.297855865613987, 0.287261150364813, 0.293374469828208, 0.28710187409247, 
0.426691163020906, 0.343033292092993, 0.47018174096222, 0.295890385833758, 
0.17462549544427, 0.32444207224037, 1.15960193451398, 1.43487842039073, 
1.1954881211204, 0.694670633111126, 1.03274740893889, 2.42996854423028, 
2.10287709536259, 1.15310473651356, 0.930494475702483, 0.800362608672448, 
0.670946160047344, 0.917149369794335, 0.969963623056172, 0.356546865546547, 
1.01767041791117, 0.437905647321569, 0.628994758168588, 0.475946636660009, 
0.41227308378791, 0.453016082808868, 0.504440080025434, 0.423426859723028, 
0.355655416919196, 0.549594966348079, 0.371544423161221, 0.396618119014455, 
0.426581724604903, 0.457564804982094, 0.406227408970275, 0.66592753876014, 
0.429242005148684, 0.308938181405404, 0.357491106253483, 0.400417939035907, 
0.452558426733727, 0.332516184043711, 0.336734593477769, 0.385984313372426, 
0.415257522282799, 0.416877219867739, 0.437870609858534, 0.504826034458151, 
0.3692029958207, 0.421086132923672, 0.398797799365072, 0.345820252410603, 
0.428961656779362, 0.343022005040261, 0.43859585449659, 0.351397709779422, 
0.441831474644956, 0.395322591846656, 0.42707677378149, 0.383038227789757, 
0.419372655758695, 1.20999057171145, 1.0324754309382, 1.15390937655487, 
1.27269225907284, 1.52681925668428, 1.24850012592141, 1.25692362442215, 
1.66191343132771, 1.52396351968135, 1.30216898419267, 0.979390794690607, 
0.84785205830123, 0.964426984707154, 0.977438888352537, 0.792711561574157, 
2.02183603756457, 0.813045009817121, 1.22303796362965, 1.29689832478866, 
1.47601961377895, 0.900469664727307, 0.982591604164768)), row.names = 300:585, class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you

Comment: voting to close as caused by a typo (see comment-like answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you aren't saving the lines to the plot, you are adding them without saving them. Add something like:

```
a <- fig + geom_abline(data = lines, aes(intercept=intercept, slope=slope, color=name, size=name, linetype=name))+
  scale_color_manual(name='Size',
                     values=c("Sw ~ Re^13/15" ='#e66419', "Sw ~ Re^9/10" ='#e66419',
                              "Sw ~ Re^2/3" ='#278ccf', "Sw ~ Re^3/4" ='#278ccf',
                              'Fish' = '#e66419', 'Larvae' = '#278ccf'),
                     breaks=lines$name) +
  scale_size_manual(name='Size',
                    values=c("Sw ~ Re^13/15" =1, "Sw ~ Re^9/10" =1.25, "Sw ~ Re^2/3" =1, "Sw ~ Re^3/4" = 1.25)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name='Size',
                        values=c("Sw ~ Re^13/15" ='solid', "Sw ~ Re^9/10" ='dashed',
                                 "Sw ~ Re^2/3" ='solid', "Sw ~ Re^3/4" ='dashed'))


b <- fig2 + geom_abline(data = lines1, aes(intercept=intercept, slope=slope, color=name, size=name, linetype=name))+
  scale_color_manual(name='Size',
                     values=c("St ~ Re^-2/15" ='#e66419', "St ~ Re^-1/10" ='#e66419',
                              "St ~ Re^-1/3" ='#278ccf', "St ~ Re^-1/4" ='#278ccf',
                              'Fish' = '#e66419', 'Larvae' = '#278ccf'),
                     breaks=lines$name) +
  scale_size_manual(name='Size',
                    values=c("St ~ Re^-2/15" =1, "St ~ Re^-1/10" =1.25, "St ~ Re^-1/3" =1, "St ~ Re^-1/4" = 1.25)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name='Size',
                        values=c("St ~ Re^-2/15" ='solid', "St ~ Re^-1/10" ='dashed',
                                 "St ~ Re^-1/3" ='solid', "St ~ Re^-1/4" ='dashed'))
```

The try plotting both (I used `cowplot`):

```
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(a, b, labels = NA, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jpsmith. Do you know how could I convert the text in the legend to a mathematical expression with superscript and subscripts? Thank you

Comment: Look into `bquote()` - i.e. `bquote(hat(R))` will print the hat symbol on R